# How to solve $y'' -2\,y'+2\,y = \cos(x)\,e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So to come to a quick end:

For the particular solution I've chosen the ansatz

$y_p  = a\,x\,\cos(x)\,e^x$

in orientation to the formula.
However, if I plug this in the Differential equation I get:

$-2\,a\,e^x\,\sin(x)$

I see no way how this could be equal to

$\cos(x)\,e^x$

so did I pick a wrong approach - try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use the method of undetermined coefficients to find particular solution for an ODE of this form :
$$
a_{n}(x)\frac{d^{n}y}{dx^{n}}+a_{n-1}\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}}+\cdots+a_{1}(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+a_{0}(x)=g(x)
$$
For a non-zero $a_{n}(x)$, it depends on how $g(x)$ is defined. You claim $y_{p}:=ax\cos(x)e^{x}$ when you should have tried :
$$
y_{p}:=(c_{1}x+c_{0})e^{x}(\cos(x)+\sin(x))
$$

Comment: worked, thank you. indeed I just dropped sine.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'' -2\,y'+2\,y = \cos(x)\,e^x$$
$$(ye^{-x})'' +ye^{-x} = \cos(x)$$
$$w'' +w = \cos(x)$$
Where $w=e^{-x}y$.

Try for the particular solution:
$$w_p= Ax \sin x $$
You will find that $A=\dfrac 12$ then:
$$w_p=\dfrac 12 x \sin x$$
$$\implies y_p=\dfrac 12e^x x \sin x$$